# Using JQuery to track FAQs in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

So I am trying to work out which FAQs from our site are the most popular. I thought using GA would be the best way, so tried to use some of the existing JQuery that the user clicks to Open a question would be reusable:

```
<div class="faq">
    <div class="question" id="q<?= $i; ?>">
    <?php the_sub_field('faq_question'); ?>
    <span class="ico icon-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
    <?php the_sub_field('faq_answer'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.faq').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
<!-- dodgy new code starts here  -->
        var linkText = $(this).html();
        alert(linkText);
        ga('send', 'event',  'FAQ', linkText);
<!-- end dodgy new code -->
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately linkText is the whole Question and Answer. When rendered on the page, the html displays as:

```
<h3>General FAQ</h3>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="question" id="q1">
      How many roads must a man walk down, before you can call him a man?
      <span class="ico icon-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
     <div class="answer">
        <p>The answer is "blowing in the wind".</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How can I send either the Question ID or the actual question to the GA function, using JQuery? I have done a million variations, but I don't know JQuery or Javascript well enough to not be just randomly trying stuff and hoping it works ... this has not been as effective as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, It's been a while I done the analytics part to know if that implementation is correct but I guess you have that under control.

to get the question

```
$('.faq .question').on('click', function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 var linkText = $this.text();

 $this.toggleClass('open);
 ga('send', 'event',  'FAQ', linkText);
});
```

to get the id

```
$('.faq .question').on('click', function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 var questionId = $this.attr('id');

 $this.toggleClass('open);
 ga('send', 'event',  'FAQ', questionId);
});
```